# SQL - Inserir valores aleatórios em uma tabela

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Olá eu estou tentando inserir valores aleatórios na colunas porém sem sucesso.
Tentei isso mas não consegui nada. Alguém que possa ajudar por gentileza.

```
Declare @NovosID int
SELECT @NovosID=NovosID FROM Loja.dbo.Itens_Ale WHERE UsuarioID = @UsuarioID

INSERT INTO Loja.dbo.S_Itens (UsuarioID, Vaga, ID, Quantidade, Código, Nome, Ordenar, Verificar, Data)
        VALUES (@UsuarioID, @Vagas, @NovosID, '1', 'Site', @ItemNome, @OrdenarNu, '1', @GetData);
```

Tentei essa gambiarra mas sem sucesso. Dentro da tabela_Ale tem somente 4 itens com os ID `101/106/112/194` Então quero que ele faça uma escolha aleatória desses números para enviar para a outra tabela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta usar a função `RAND` para selecionar um valor inteiro aleatório de uma tabela. No exemplo a seguir criei a tabela `valores` com uma coluna de identificação (`id`) e com uma coluna `valor` com os dados possíveis:

```
CREATE TABLE valores(
  id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
  valor INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO valores(id, valor)
             VALUES(1, 101),
                   (2, 106),
                   (3, 112),
                   (4, 194);
```

Depois disso, para buscar algum valor, basta usar a função `RAND` no `WHERE`:

```
SELECT v.valor
  FROM valores v
 WHERE v.id = FLOOR(RAND() * 3 + 1)
```

---

> [`RAND`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
>
> Retorna um valor `float` pseudoaleatório de 0 a 1, exclusivo.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, ficou perfeito.